# SCIFI story about a game show that results in death of the contestants

Tags: story-identification

I am trying to find a SciFi story I read years ago.  I thought it was by Philip K Dick but cannot find it among his stories.  In the story, a man who is down on his luck decides to apply for a game show.  He is accepted and is a contestant in a survival game -- if he lasts long enough, he wins but he is more likely to die because everyone is after him.  In the end he hijacks a plane and flies it into the game show producer's building.  Anyone recognize that plot?

Comment: Can you recall any other details that might be helpful?

Comment: [Running man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Running_Man_(novel))?

Comment: Definitely the Running Man, the book version.

Answer (score 18):

This is almost certainly:

**[The Running Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Running_Man_(novel))** by **[Stephen King](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stephen_King)** published in 1982 under the [pseudonym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudonym) [Richard Bachman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Bachman).

[image: The Running Man novel cover]

The story has the game show you describe (from wikipedia):

> The contestant is declared an enemy of the state and released with a
>   12-hour head start before the Hunters, an elite team of
>   Network-employed hitmen, are sent out to kill him. The contestant
>   earns $100 per hour that he stays alive and avoids capture, an
>   additional $100 for each law enforcement officer or Hunter he kills,
>   and a grand prize of $1 billion if he survives for 30 days. Viewers
>   can receive cash rewards for informing the Network of the runner's
>   whereabouts. The runner is given $4,800 and a pocket video camera
>   before he leaves the studio. He can travel anywhere in the world, and
>   each day he must videotape two messages and mail them back to the
>   studio for broadcasting. If he neglects to send the messages, he will
>   be held in default of his Games contract and stop accumulating prize
>   money, but will continue to be hunted indefinitely.

Culminates in a plane hijacking (again wikipedia):

> Richards takes McCone and Amelia as hostages and has the plane fly low
>   over populated areas to avoid being shot down by a surface-to-air
>   missile. However, Killian calls Richards aboard the plane and reveal
>   that he knows Richards does not have any explosives, as the plane's
>   security system would have detected them.

Ends with that plane crashing into the TV tower:

> The book ends with the plane crashing into the tower, resulting in the
>   deaths of Richards and Killian. The novel closes with the description,
>   "... and it rained fire twenty blocks away."

As @starpilotsix notes in the comments to the question, your description is most likely the novel version.  The movie version is different in some ways.

Comment: Definitely different, yes. Richards doesn't say "I'll be back" in the novel.

Comment: Also the book was dire whereas the film was a work of towering genius.

Comment: Note that originally *The Running Man* was published under King's pen name "Richard Bachman" and was anthologized in the 80s in a volume called *The Bachman Books* (which also included *Thinner*, IIRC).

Comment: Added a linked mention of the pen name.